# Trouble casting a long as a Double

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been working with google firebase's realtime Database on android in order to graph data in real time. When I am retrieving the data from the database it is setting it to type long. I am then trying to cast this data as a double but it is not working.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.helper.StaticLabelsFormatter;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Set up GraphView
    GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
     final LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>();
    graph.addSeries(series);

    //Initialize Database
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.child("Electric").setValue("value set");
    mDatabase.child("Water").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Double xl = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue();
            Double yl = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("Value").getValue();

            double x =  xl.doubleValue();
            double y =  yl.doubleValue();
            new DataPoint(x ,y);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });



}
}
```

with this error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                        
   Process: com.example.seniordesign.homemonitoringapp, PID: 3765
                                                                                          java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
                                                                                              at com.example.seniordesign.homemonitoringapp.MainActivity$1.onChildAdded(MainActivity.java:35)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbox.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZT(Unknown Source)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5731)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using this graphing library http://www.android-graphview.org/

Comment: Note that `long` is not the same as `Long`.

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: try to convert to string first. then Double.valueOf(numberAsString);

Comment: @ZeroOne Why do you want to make it harder than it needs to be?

Comment: Hint: you want us to spend our time to help you. So you please spend the 3 minutes it takes to properly format / indent all of your question. Those stack traces with zillions of spaces requiring to scroll like crazy are really annoying :-(

Answer (score 3):

The key here is to understand the difference between the built-in types `long` and `double` and their wrapper counterparts `Long` and `Double`. The rules of Java's type system will allow you to cast from a `long` to a `double` and vice versa. However, since `Long` and `Double` are objects, references can only be cast in accordance to the rules used for all references. In particular, you can only cast from a child to a parent (which can happen implicitly) or from a parent to a child in an inheritance hierarchy. `Long` and `Double` both extend `Number` and so are siblings.

Since the objects returned by `getValue()` are `Long`, you should cast to `Long` instead of `Double`:

```
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Long xl = (Long) dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue();
        Long yl = (Long) dataSnapshot.child("Value").getValue();

        double x =  xl.doubleValue();
        double y =  yl.doubleValue();
        new DataPoint(x ,y);

    }
```

As a side note, if you are storing the "time" and "Value" data, you might want to consider revising the code that saves these values so that they are stored as `Double` to begin with. Then you will have less issues with retrieving the values here.

Comment: _Since the objects returned by getValue() are Long, you should cast to Long instead of Double_ . it returns a type Object and it could be Boolean,
String,
Long,
Double,
Map<String, Object> or
List<Object> check reference 
 [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue())

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw In this particular case, the `Object` reference returned refers whose concrete type is `Long`. My statement in the answer isn't incorrect, but it can certainly be improved to be more clear.

Comment: I think your explanation is just fine.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Glad you understood despite my mangled edits and final comment version.